# How to configure spring boot web app with redis using Docker

Tags: docker, redis, spring-boot, docker-compose

I have a small spring boot web application which saves the data to redis.

After running docker-compose.yml containers are started but on `localhost:8085` i have "The connection was reset".

#### spring boot aplication.yml

```
server:
    address: 127.0.0.1
---
spring:
    profiles: development
server:
    address: 127.0.0.1
---
spring:
    profiles: production
server:
    address: 127.0.0.1
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: docker_app
  ports:
   - "8085:8080"
  links:
   - redis

redis:  
    image: redis
```

How do I link spring boot and redis?

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is the wrong address. Use `redis` as the hostname.

Comment: You are right. I can't use address 127.0.0.1 in docker and redis as hostname works.